# URL Rewriting and Rack base paths

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, rack

I'm trying to set up a Rails website on Bluehost and I'm having trouble with the path helpers. As I don't want to monkey-patch Rails, I'm trying to solve this through .htaccess. Here's the scenario:

1. I'm hosting `www.engradado.com` on `public_html/engradado`, which points to `rails_apps/engradado/public`
2. I'm rewriting `www.engradado.com` to point to `www.engradado.com/engradado`, through this `public_html/.htaccess` file:

   ```
   # BlueHost.com
   # .htaccess main domain to subdirectory redirect
   # Copy and paste the following code into the .htaccess file
   # in the public_html folder of your hosting account
   # make the changes to the file according to the instructions.
   # Do not change this line.
   RewriteEngine on
   # Change example.com to be your main domain.
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?engradado.com$
   # Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain.
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/engradado/
   # Don't change these line.
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   # Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain.
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /engradado/$1
   # Change example.com to be your main domain again.
   # Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain
   # followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc.
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?engradado.com$
   RewriteRule ^(/)?$ engradado/ [L]
   ```
3. Here's my `rails_apps/engradado/public/.htaccess`:

   ```
   Options -MultiViews
   PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
   #Set this to whatever environment you'll be running in
   RailsEnv production
   #RackBaseURI /
   #PassengerAppRoot /home2/engradad/rails_apps/engradado
   RackBaseURI /engradado
   SetEnv GEM_HOME /home2/engradad/ruby/gems
   ```
4. Whenever I call a path helper, e.g. `root_url` or `news_path`, it prepends `/engradado` to the path, so instead of `root_url => "http://www.engradado.com/"` it prints `root_url => "http://www.engradado.com/engradado/"`, and `news_path(1) => "engradado/news/1"` instead of `news_path(1) => "news/1"`.

How can I solve this so `/engradado` isn't prepended to the url?

Comment: If this is pasted from your actual file, you've got a typo on the last line. It says engrandad instead of engrandado. (This won't answer your question, but it may cause other problems if you don't fix it.)

Comment: That's actually correct. The username is 8 characters long.

Comment: Ah, I got confused, thinking that that was the same path that you were reweriting to. Thanks for the clarification.